# UIView Multiple Transform

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, transform, gestures

I have trouble with rotating and scalling my UIView and I haven't found any solution.

Here is sample:

```
@IBAction func rotateMazeView(_ sender: UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
    mazeView.transform = mazeView.transform.rotated(by: sender.rotation)
}
@IBAction func scaleMazeView(_ sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {

    let scaleFactor = sender.scale

    mazeView.transform = mazeView.transform.concatenating((CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleFactor, y: scaleFactor)))
}
```

When I rotate this view, rotation speed is unbelievable fast. The same problem with scale function. 
Why I don't use just `view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleFactor, y: scaleFactor)`? In this case, when the view was rotate and I am starting to scale, the view return to origin position.

I need to implement difficult transforming with this view.
Hope that the answer help many other people.

Comment: I have found solution. We need to use all "moving" things in draw method of UIView. We can't change position correctly without redrawing out  view.

Comment: So I apply my transform on drawing path and call setNeedsDisplay() to redraw. By this method we can use a lot of transformation and quality still looks good. When we scale view without redrawing, we can see some pixels on view.